# How to use case in laravel with join and with condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Basically I have 2 tables

1. users
2. relation

So what I want is when I enter my search query (username ) so it should search in my database using like function and then those users which listed after `like` function should automatically check  if `myuserid` follows the listed `user.id` from relation table.

**Users table**

```
Id |uid |username |pwd
```

**Relation table**

```
Id|folllwedbyid|followedtoid|ruid|rtd(timestamp)
```

`relation.ruid`  is like :

```
"$myid=7382;""users.id=7272 ""so relation.ruid =73827272"
```

```php
DB::table('users') 
    ->join('relation','relation.followetoid','=','users.id')
    ->whereNotIn('users.id',[$myid])
    ->select('users.id','users.username',DB::raw('(CASE WHEN relation.ruid = ' . $myid . ' users.id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS is_user')
    ->get();
```

Comment: And where is your code ??

Comment: https://pastebin.com/gv9nFSrf

Comment: Next question, what's wrong with your code?

Comment: @miken32 error says 1064 syntax error near THEN

Comment: Suggest you read on proper syntax for `CASE` statement. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html

Comment: And don't put variables directly into your query. It's very unsafe. Use `selectRaw` with parameters instead. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-methods